# How to align ion-label in center?

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and using ion-label to print some text.I have facing issue with ion-label , i will assign ion-label to center but did not work. which css or ionic pre defined css used ? Below my css code give ...

```css
.User_Label_Section {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 107px;
}

.user_Name {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ion-row class="User_Label_Section">
  <ion-col text-center>
    <ion-label class="user_Name">ABCDEFG</ion-label>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: do you want to make it vertical center?

Comment: Sir, not vertical center , only horizontal center.

Comment: i checked its seems its already center to .user_Name, do let me know if you need center to entire body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give width as 100vw to .user_Name class. It will work if you want it to be aligned in centre. The issue is you have fixed the width: 200px and are trying to align the text within it. Then again this will fix the issue with the css part.

Comment: VW, VH may makes issues on different screen resolution, right? It's better to specify in %  itself.

Comment: if you give 100vw to some div then it means you want it centre aligned always in any screen size(for the particular usecase). It will change if your use case changes accordingly. Vw is meant to take the screen size of the whole screen always. % can also be use if you wanted to align according to a parent div here but that was not the case so both will work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to go back to the drawing board with this and look at the way that Ionic 4 works with default styles.

This article explains the built-in classes available to you including some flex options:

- [CSS Utilities - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities)

The `ion-row` and `ion-col` already have flex stuff applied to them so you are fighting them and perhaps causing issues:

- [Responsive Grid - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid)

In general your best bet would be to lean on what the framework already provides, as that is going to be the best tested options, and then

Also, a tip for future reference: using `text-center` as a directive like that is more of an Ionic 3 way of doing things.

The new recommended way is to apply this using `class="ion-text-center"`.

This is because you can't add these directives like `text-center` in React or Vue so they standardised on using classes for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

`width: 100%` is enough to do that

```css
.User_Label_Section {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 107px;

}

.user_Name {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ion-row class="User_Label_Section">
  <ion-col text-center>
    <ion-label class="user_Name">ABCDEFG</ion-label>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove width like below

```
.user_Name {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex`   on `ion-col` and `margin: auto` on `ion-label`

```
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col style="display: flex;">
        <ion-label style="margin:auto;">ABCDEFG</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But you can try this. It may work.

```
 .user_Name {
      text-align: center;
      width: 200px;
    }
```